# java code to store patients details and to view details

Tags: java

Java code to implement patient appointment system and the user should be prompted with                          following menu:

1. Add a new patient entry
2. Display patient name for a appointment time and date
3. Display patient entry
4. Exit

Constraints are:

1. There should not be more than 10 appointments for a doctor
2. No re-entry of time and date that has been appointed

i am new to java programming and i have no idea how to start. please help me in coding

Comment: You need to read up on how to use `Scanner`, how to use `HashMap` and how to use `SimpleDateFormat`.  If you have a more specific question afterwards, then come back and ask it.  But currently, this question is far too broad.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. First you have to store your data in database.use mysql or other database for do this stuff and then Design the er diagram for your system.just google it how to draw the er diagram for your system and then create the tables from the diagram.

Read JDBC tutorial for integrate and read database records in java code.